# How to Serialize ICollection<T> as List<T> to Xml?

Tags: c#, reflection, xmlserializer

I am trying to dynamically serialize a List to Xml.
I am able to do so, as long I do not have a ICollection as a property of T.

I would like to dynamically overwrite the ICollection type into List before I write it to Xml.

This is what I have so far.

```
List<-XmlElementAttribute-> attrToConvertList = new List<-XmlElementAttribute->();

foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
{
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name == "ICollection`1")
    {
        XmlElementAttribute attrToConvert = new XmlElementAttribute();
        attrToConvert.ElementName = propertyInfo.Name;
        attrToConvert.Type = typeof(List<>);
        attrToConvert.Type = attrToConvert.Type.MakeGenericType(propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
        attrToConvertList.Add(attrToConvert);
    }
}
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attributesToConvert = new XmlAttributes();

foreach (var xmlElementAttribute in attrToConvertList)
    attributesToConvert.XmlElements.Add(xmlElementAttribute);

overrides.Add(typeof(T), attributesToConvert);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), overrides);
```

I get the error that I cannot serialize the type ICollection because it is an interface.
I was under the impression that what I was doing with the XmlAttributeOverrides was supposed to overwrite the ICollection to the type List.

Comment: better to use DataContract serialization instead of Xml Searialization if iterface type is used. Check out this for Type Supported by DataContract Serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx

Comment: I solved my original issue by using Newton.Json to serialize the object.

Answer (score 0):

XML serialization doesn't handle interfaces, and apparently XmlAttributeOverride doesn't allow you to bypass that behavior.  You can change the type of your property, or make a type, for serialization only, where the property is a `List<T>`.

Example:

```
class RealClass
{
    ICollection<int> SomeInts { get; set; }
}

class MySerializationClass
{
    private readonly RealClass _wrappedObject;
    public SerializationClass() : this(new RealClass()) { }
    public SerializationClass(RealClass wrappedObject)
    {
        _wrappedObject = wrappedObject;
    }
    public List<T> SomeInts
    {
        get { return new List<T>(_wrappedObject.SomeInts); }
        set { _wrappedObject.SomeInts = value; }
    }
}
```

You could also do this with explicit interface member implementation, and use the interface in most of your code:

```
interface IHaveSomeInts
{
    ICollection<int> SomeInts { get; set; }
}

class TheClass : IHaveSomeInts
{
    public List<T> SomeInts { get; set; }
    ICollection<T> IHaveSomeInts.SomeInts
    {
        get { return SomeInts; }
        set { SomeInts = new List<T>(value); }
    }
}
```

When assigning an `ICollection<T>` to an `IList<T>`, I would probably use `as` to see if I can just cast the object rather than creating a new one, to avoid creating lists needlessly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I am working on a library that would allow anyone to give an object and I would save that to XML (https://datasampler.codeplex.com/). Since I do not know the object before hand, it would be great if I could change from an ICollection to List at runtime.

Comment: @jsucupira aha, that does indeed make the problem more complicated.  I suppose you can either use code generation to use one of the approaches I suggest, or you could write your own XML serializer.  I'd be inclined to do the latter (depending on the scope of the project), especially since the object you get from "anyone" could have members of *any* interface type; the type of the object implementing the interface could be internal, and not available to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my original issue by using Newton.Json to serialize the object.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did this so others will also benefit from your solution?

Comment: Instead of creating my own serializer I am using the library Newton.Json from Nuget to serialize my objects.